# i want to completely uninstall npm on windows , i need a help in this

Tags: npm, uninstallation

In my system i want to completely uninstall npm and install a specific version which is used in my project , so i need help to uninstall npm  totally in my windows.

i tried this but at last iam getting the error

To completely remove npm, you need to perform the following steps:

Open your terminal or command prompt.

Check if you have any version of npm installed by typing npm -v and press Enter.

If npm is installed, type npm -g ls and press Enter. This will show you all the packages installed globally with npm.

For Windows users: type where npm and press Enter. This will show you where npm is installed.

To remove npm, type sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/share/man/man1/node.1 /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d ~/.npm ~/.node-gyp /opt/local/bin/node /opt/local/include/node /opt/local/lib/node_modules and press Enter.

error iam getting:

( C:\Users\Admin>sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/share/man/man1/node.1 /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d ~/.npm ~/.node-gyp /opt/local/bin/node /opt/local/include/node /opt/local/lib/node_modules
'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.)